# past-continuous vs present-perfect-continuous

Tags: perfect-aspect, continuous-aspect, perfect-continuous

I have watched a few videos on this theme, but still don't understand when I would use one and cannot use another. Example from one of BBC English videos:

"I have been cooking soup for 20 minutes when the phone rang"

Here they used pres-perf-cont (and not past-cont) only because there is a note that the process was continued for 20 minutes?

What exactly would happen if I said "I was cooking soup for 20 minutes when the phone rang". 'cooking' is a progressive action, that happened in the past at the precise moment(phone rang), it's also OK according to the grammar, not?

Comment: Your *I have been cooking soup for 20 minutes when the phone rang* is ***syntactically invalid***, because Present Perfect ***have been cooking*** must be followed by a Present tense clause *(when the phone **rings**)*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Or "I _had_ been cooking soup for 20 minutes when the phone rang." I wonder if the OP has made a transcription error in the post.

Comment: @FumbleFingers:  you're right: I read it quickly, and missed that. The original must have been _I had been cooking soup_.

Comment: I knew the BBC wouldn't be that careless. The actual example is [*I **had** been cooking soup for 20 minutes when the phone rang.*](https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/oromo/features/learnersquestions/pastperfectsimpleorcontinuous) I consider that grounds for closevoting for lack of prior research.

Comment: The following is more natural than the first sentence: *I have been cooking soup for 20 minutes when the phone **rings**.* That's a common narrative technique. But I disagree that the first sentence is syntactically wrong. It's simply not idiomatic (and would like not be used)—because there are more common verb forms in that construction.

Comment: Friends, what about the difference?))))

Let's say "when the phone rings". 

When I should use present-perfect-continious, and when past-continuous??